# Time machine failing to backup as sparsebundle is already in use

Tags: macos, mac, time-machine, airport-extreme

I have an airport extreme with a drive connected, and use it for backing up snow leopard macs. I have an occasional problem with one of them that says "the backup disk image ... is already in use" and it fails to backup.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me in the end was to "disconnect all users" from the Airport Utility - and then unplug/plugin the drive again (remount it) - it was then able to backup successfully.

Comment: I think it's just a temporary solution as I still have the error message from time to time :(

Comment: disconnect all users isn't available in the latest version (6), but you can download 5.6 from apple - http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1482

Comment: more info on this procedure at http://pondini.org/TM/C12.html

Answer (score 4):

There isn't an .InProgress file still on the drive is there?  That can cause problems.
Just delete it to get the backup working again.

Comment: This is a pretty good suggestion; upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

The disconnect, power off/on works, but only temporarily. I think for me it hoses up if I close my macbook pro lid while its trying to backup.

Comment: FWIW - this seems to be solved now, post a few updates to OS-X

Comment: does not seem to be fixed in 10.7.1